# On Boarding Azure Active Directory for Azure Cloud App

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services, openid-connect

I am getting below error While On-Boarding Azure Active Directory Authentication for the application which is hosted in Azure Cloudapp.

I have configured endpoint as https://127.0.0.1:443/ in cloud project.
but if I run application on local and verified the port number in Emulator. this time that is increased by one ("https://127.0.0.1:444/").
So AAD is try to call back (https://127.0.0.1:443/) it is giving below error.

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply
>   address 'https://127.0.0.1:444/' does not match the reply address
>   'https://127.0.0.1:443/' provided when requesting Authorization code.

Answer (score -1):

AAD uses the reply address as an identifier as part of the login process. It is how it finds the application to log you in with. If you change the identifier it won't have the same identity and will fail because the credentials no longer match.

This is like having the login name bob1, and wondering why you can't log in with bob2. The addition makes it a completely different identity.